# React Native Android biometrics - can I locally authenticate using face lock? From what I see, only fingerprint authentication works

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

I can set a fingerprint and a face unlock on my Android phone and currently I am trying to check if either is available and biometrically authenticate the user in my application.

I am currently using the react-native-biometrics package which supports both TouchID and FaceID for iOS, but only Biometrics for Android. When I do this:

```
const { biometryType } = await biometrics.isSensorAvailable();
```

It is only defined if I have a fingerprint unlock set up.

```
    const { success } = await biometrics.simplePrompt({
        promptMessage: 'Confirmation',
    });
```

Also only triggers if I have fingerprint unlock set up. It doesn't do anything if I just have face unlock set up.

From what I can see, all React Native libraries that I have found only support fingerprint for Android. I imagine there must be some sort of Android reason for this?